# int does not contain a definition for Getawaiter + asp.net core web api async

Tags: asp.net-core, task, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement the async CRUD functionality for my application using asp.net core webapi. I have been told to only use stored procedures for doing any requests to the database. I have implemented the async for the get request but struggling to the same for create request. Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong in my code?

I am getting the following error message in my repository method in the await line of code

[image]

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Movies")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMovie([FromBody] MoviesDto movies)
{
    if (movies == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // Check if movie exists
    var movie =  _moviesRepository.GetMovie(movies.MovieId);

    if (movie == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var results = Mapper.Map<Movies>(movies);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _moviesRepository.AddMovie(results);
    }

    return Ok(results);
}
```

Repository method:

```
public async Task AddMovie(Movies movie)
{
    await _mrdbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.spInsertMovie {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", movie.Title,movie.ReleaseYear,movie.Plot,movie.MovieLength,"Ranjit Menon","");
}
```

New repository method:

```
public async Task AddMovie(Movies movie)
{
    object[] parameters =
            {
                new SqlParameter("@val1", movie.Title),
                new SqlParameter("@val2", movie.ReleaseYear),
                new SqlParameter("@val3", movie.Plot),
                new SqlParameter("@val4", movie.MovieLength),
                new SqlParameter("@val5", "Ranjit Menon"),

                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@retVal",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                    Value = -1
                }
        };

    await  _mrdbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC  @retVal = dbo.spInsertMovie @val1, @val2, @val3, @val4,@val5", CancellationToken.None , parameters);
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertMovie]
    (@Title varchar(50),  
     @ReleaseYear int, 
     @Plot varchar(50), 
     @MovieLength int, 
     @CreatedBy varchar(20)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    ----------------------------------------
    -- variables
    ----------------------------------------

    -- error
    declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048), @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int, @MovieID int

    ----------------------------------------
    -- insert record
    ----------------------------------------

    begin try


        -- insert record
            insert into [dbo].[Movies]
                       ([Title]
                       ,[ReleaseYear]
                       ,[Plot]
                       ,[MovieLength]                      
                       ,[CreatedBy]                    
                       ,[UpdatedBy])
            values
                       (@Title
                       ,@ReleaseYear
                       ,@Plot
                       ,@MovieLength                     
                       ,@CreatedBy
                       ,@CreatedBy)


        -- get assigned id
        set @MovieID = scope_identity()



    end try
    begin catch
        select @ErrorMessage = dbo.fnGetErrorMessage('Insert Movie Record', error_message(), object_schema_name(@@procid), object_name(@@procid), error_line()), @ErrorSeverity = error_severity(), @ErrorState = error_state();
        raiserror(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        return
    end catch

    -- return assigned id
    select @MovieID as MovieID

END
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` most likely returns an int, not a Task. Use `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommandasync(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I have just added the new repository method as per your suggestion. However I dont see the procedure getting called. I have switched on my profiler to capture the call. I have tested my stored procedure in the backend by passing the same parameter values and it works fine by returning the newly generated Movie ID. I have also update the post to contain the storeprocedure

Comment: @Tom does it throw an exception or fail in any way?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am seeing no exception thrown which makes it difficult for me to understand why its not working.